# Android studio methods separator

Tags: android, android-studio

How to add line separator afer every method.

like this:

[image: Line separator android studio]

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Simply enable in settings

```
Appearance: Show method separators
```

Or hit <kbd>Shift</kbd> 2 times in Editor Area and type `method separators`

[image]

Comment: @AlexKost You're right, it doesn't work for Kotlin. Would be nice if you can fire a bug in their ticket system.

Comment: Is there any way to change the color of that seperator?

Comment: @KwnstantinosNikoloutsos sure thing. "Settings -> Editor -> Color Scheme -> General -> Code -> Method separator color"

Answer (score 11):

Go to Preferences > Editor > General > Appearance > Show method separators > check the box

[image]